# Javascript object prototype error

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

I need new method for the object. And I'm trying to create it:

```
Object.prototype.getByPath = function (path, other) {
    for (var i=0, obj=this, path = path.split('.'), len=path.length; i<len; i++) {
        obj = obj[path[i]];
    }
    return (typeof obj === "undefined" || obj == "") ? other : obj;
}
```

But this code return an error (Conflict with another js file!):

> Uncaught TypeError: Object function (path, other) {

Another js file start with this line:

```
(function(){function d(a,b){
    try {
      for (var c in b)
        Object.defineProperty(a.prototype, c, {value:b[c],enumerable:!1})
    } catch(d) {
      a.prototype = b
    }
}());
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Can you post a demo to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Are you sure you want to add to the `Object` prototype?? This will add the `getByPath` method to **all** objects

Comment: Yeah, it's not recommended (or even efficient) to do this.

Comment: Do you know any right way to solve this?

Comment: I'll guess that "starts with this line" ends in `());`.

Comment: @Teemu—I think the OP assumes that each property is an object until the end. Not very robust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Conflict with another js file!

Yes it happens because it is adding the new method to all the objects , Instead try to make your own base object for all your clients side javascript objects,

```
var yourBaseObj={
  getByPath :function (path, other) {
    for (var i=0, obj=this, path = path.split('.'), len=path.length; i<len; i++) {
        obj = obj[path[i]];
    }
    return (typeof obj === "undefined" || obj == "") ? other : obj;
  }
}
```

And then you it for other objects ,

```
function YourNewObject(){

}
YourNewObject.prototype=yourBaseObj
```

Comment: +1, but also because the "other library" has not taken precautions against inherited properties when using for..in.